# KAA MongoDB server, Data not retrived sent from Raspberry Pi

Tags: amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, sandbox, kaa

I am running this example http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/ .

But data is not storing on the server side.
What should I do now?
When I running db.logs_my_application_token.
find() from mongo console,
it is showing nothing.
Do I have to provide some IP or host in my code, I am using KAA SANDBOX from AWS.

Console Output of Raspberry Pi attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB3Uv.png) here...

Comment: Can you provide server logs?

Comment: Do you use Java SDK?

Comment: @KirillLiubun am using C SDK

Comment: @KirillLiubun and my server logs are some what like  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4lXltJAgdN5SzRvdU5GdWdsR3c and https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4lXltJAgdN5RmVnSnRSZFBDRnM

Comment: It seems that you have some problems with internet connection or you configured AWS instance incorrectly and your client tries to connect to a wrong port. Try to connect to the server with Java SDK, if logs don't appear in mongo then the problem in AWS configuration.

Comment: @KirillLiubun Can you explain me how to implement it with Java SDK, I think Raspberry Pi is not compatible with Java SDK. It supports only C and C++ SDK.

Comment: You don't need to run Java on Raspberry Pi (but if you want, see [Java SE Embedded on the Raspberry Pi](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html)), just download data collection demo from [sample applications board](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Getting-started/#launching-your-first-kaa-application) and execute jar file in order to connect EP to Kaa server.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I am able to do that using ..

Perform these two steps may be this can solve your problem.

1. Just run this command on host machine

   ```
   sudo /usr/lib/kaa-sandbox/bin/change_kaa_host.sh $new host name/ip$
   ```
2. Then change the IP address of using Admin UI, for that you need to
   sign in using username : kaa and passwword : kaa123
    then go to setting > general setting then change the IP address preceded by :8080, enter your machine's public IP address, that can be easily accessible from anywhere.

Tips :: if you are using AWS instance then use public IP address of your instance.

Further error persist then drop your previous instance and launch a new instance.

For more details go the official documentation page

Hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to provide IP address.
You should download the generated SDK file and compile it with the source code. and then run it.